# C#: Access object-method inside multidimensional array inside Generic List

Tags: list, variables, multidimensional-array

I would like to manually change a value of a public variable inside an object that's stored in a multidimensional array. The array is stored in a`List<T>`

Something like this:

```
areaList[0].array[90, 50].type = 1;
```

The code above doesn't work.

The code below works, but doesn't fill the purpose, since I just want to change one variable of a single object stored in the array.

```
foreach (Area[,] area in areaList]
{
area[90, 50].type = 1;
}
```

**[EDIT]
I found out that I could initialize a reference of the object like this:**

```
Area[,] green = areaList[0];
green[90, 50].type = 1;
```

And thus being able to change the variable-values of the object that's inside the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use arrayList.get(position) .

```
areaList.get(0).array[90,50].type=1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work
'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'get' and no extension method 'get'.

When i try areaList(0).array[90, 50].type=1, it doesn't work either.